# Why does QGIS save EPSG:4326 as long, lat?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, epsg

Why does QGIS save EPSG:4326 with coordinates in the longitude, latitude format? Isn't the correct standardized format latitude, longitude?

[image: s]

Comment: Axis order is a messy thing. Latitude-longitude is used in some formats, while others use longitude latitude. If you save your data into GML 3 you should get latitude-longitude order. There is lot to read about axis order in the net but when it comes to QGIS and GDAL you can read this https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc73_proj6_wkt2_srsbarn. You can read considerations about GeoJSON and CRS from https://github.com/opengeospatial/WFS_FES/tree/master/extensions/crs.